# Does Alpine's crond forward the signals and waits for the still-running scripts to exit?

Tags: cron, signals, alpine-linux

I'm running `crond` on an Alpine image (`crond -f -d 7`), and I'd like to put this setup in a CI/CD pipeline, to be redeployed automatically.

Now I'm wondering if the `crond` forwards the STOP signal to still running scripts and if it waits for them to exit, before it exits by itself.

Could not find relevant info on www.